# How to write data to a file using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, screen-scraping, chromium, puppeteer

Puppeteer exposes a `page.screenshot()` method for saving a screenshot locally on your machine. [Here are the docs.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md)

See: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://example.com');
await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
```

Is there a way to save a data file in a similar fashion. I'm seeking something analogous to...

```
page.writeToFile({data, path,});
```

Comment: What kind of data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since any puppeteer script is an ordinary node.js script you can use anything you would use in node, say the good old fs module:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('path/to/file.json', data);
```

Comment: incase you face the [Object Object] in the output just add JSON.stringify(data)

    `fs.writeFileSync('path/to/file.json', JSON.stringify(data));`